# How would you handle different formats of dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have different types of dates formatting like:

- 27 - 28 August 663 CE
- 22 August 1945 19 May
- May 4 1945 – August 22 1945
- 5/4/1945
- 2-7-1232
- 03-4-1020
- 1/3/1 `(year 1)`
- 09/08/0 `(year 0)`

Note they are all different formats, different order, some have 2 months, some only one, I tried to use [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) with no results, I also tried to use [date js](http://www.datejs.com/) yet, no luck.

I tried to do some splitting:

```
dates.push({
    Time : []
});

function doSelect(text) {
  return $wikiDOM.find(".infobox th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
  });
}
dateText = doSelect("Date").siblings('td').text().split(/\s+/g);
 for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
  d += dateText[i] + ' ';
}
dates[0].Time.push(d);
```

But the result is:

```
"Time": [
            "27 - 28 August 663 CE ",
```

Eventually what I need to auto generate is:

```
<ul class="Days">
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
</ul>

<ul class="Months">
  <li>August</li>
</ul>

<ul class="Year">
  <li>663</li>
</ul>
```

And also think of a way to handle `CE` or `AD` or `BC`

To achieve that an ideal way I'd like to use is a multidimensional array:

```
time.push({
    Day : [], 
    Month : [],
    Year : [],
    Prefix : []
});
```

Probably to check `max 2 numbers for days`, check months against a list of strings like `January, February, March..` and then the year min `3 numbers to max 4 numbers` and then handle the `prefix with some conditionals`. But yet, how about `year 2 or 1`? or how about if the date is `02/9/1975`? Or with separating `dash`, they'd be a new format. I think the logic is kinda there but how would you split those dates into a multidimensional array as per above given the fact that they are all different formats?

Comment: This is a string parsing issue that date libraries won't likely help on except for possibly validating final string(s) and is not a trivial issue

Comment: @charlietfl yes and in fact they didn't help. I'd like to split the strings, check the updated question with some extra thoughts at the end.

Comment: Probably going to need to build lots of regex for known formats that you scrape from your data (and a parser for each)  and when you come across a new one that doesn't match store it so you can write a new regex for it

Comment: @charlietfl ok i will leave this open to other users to provide ideas or solutions and i will create another questions for some specific case studies

Comment: You might have to create your own parsing engine, AST and everything.

Comment: what is or what do you mean with AST?

Comment: @charlietfl i'm starting to answer myself to this question and I will update it step by step. Feel free to contribute to the rest of the dates if you mind.

Comment: @evolutionxbox i'm starting to answer myself to this question and I will update it step by step. Feel free to contribute to the rest of the dates if you mind.

Comment: @rob.m an "AST" is part of a [compiler](https://github.com/thejameskyle/the-super-tiny-compiler) basically you've got to decipher the input and make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will be updating this answer more and more while I will build new parsers. Feel free to contribute.

So for these formats, I'll do:

```
27 - 28 August 663 CE
22 August 1945 19 May
May 4 1945 – August 22 1945
5-10 February 1720
```

JS

```
months = new Set(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]);
for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
  d += dateText[i] + ' ';
}
var words = d.replace("–", " ").replace("-", " ").replace(",", " ").replace("/", " ").split(' ');
words = $.grep(words, function(n, i){
    return (n !== "" && n != null);
});
var array = words;
var newArray = array.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
for (const word of newArray) {
 if (months.has(word)) {
   spacetime[0].Time.months.push(word);
 } else if (+word < 32) {
   spacetime[0].Time.days.push(+word);
 } else if (+word < 2200) {
   spacetime[0].Time.years.push(+word);
 } else if (/\w+/.test(word)) {
   spacetime[0].Time.suffixes.push(word);
}
```

jSon example:

```
        "Time": {
            "days": [
                22
            ],
            "months": [
                "August"
            ],
            "years": [
                1945
            ],
            "suffixes": [
                "10:25",
                "(UTC+1)"
            ]
```