# How to push and split a date into a mutidimentional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given date formats like:

- 27 - 28 August 663 CE
- 22 August 1945 19 May

How would I split that into:

```
time.push({
    Day : [], 
    Month : [],
    Year : [],
    Prefix : []
});
```

For a try out I did:

```
dateText = "27 - 28 August 663 CE";
for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
  d += dateText[i] + ' ';
}
dates[0].Time.push(d)
```

But the result is:

```
dates.push({
     "Time": [
            "27 - 28 August 663 CE ",
```

**UPDATE**

After pushing the parsed date into a multidimensional array as per above, I'd like to create:

```
<ul class="Days">
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
</ul>

<ul class="Months">
  <li>August</li>
</ul>

<ul class="Year">
  <li>663</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me what the desired output would be, could you please add an example to your question?

Comment: Don't you have to split the input to separate variables?

Comment: @tocqueville I have updated the question with the desired output

Comment: @Tinsten into different variables or into a multidimensional array, eventually I'd need to create that html as per the updated question

Comment: What's the difference between this question and [another you wrote earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417870/how-would-you-handle-different-formats-of-dates)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox that due to a comment in the other question suggesting the regex, I have provided on here 2 case studies and see how to split that. In fact I am asking how to split in this case, while the other question is broder

Comment: oh ok a duplicate, it is not a duplicate tho, the question is more specific on here, no?

Comment: Considering all the formats (also in the previous question), the task looks quite broad. Regex can be only a part of the solution, but not a solution alone, these formats are too far irregular to be parsed with _regular_ expressions.

Comment: @Teemu indeed, I am basically trying to parse dates provided on wikipedia infoboxes (the right column info box which have dates, for many articles) but they are all irregular

Comment: The regex would only be used to check for format match....then you would need a parser for that match

Comment: @charlietfl but how would you use a regex for format match? Lets say we have `27 - 28 August 663 CE`, you'd try to match it against what?

Comment: basically would do something like `if(regexObj.exec(str)){ parseString( str)}`. What you are trying to do is quite complex

Comment: @charlietfl I mean what if I go like "If string before white space has 1 number or max 2 numbers than it is a day, scrap the dash, then check if any string in the whole string match any strings in the year array "June, July, August..", if it does, then it is a month, then grab the string after the matching month (we now know it is a month) and consider it as a year, if it is not only a number, then consider the last verbal string as a prefix. Does the logic work or is it there any easier way? And this is case 1.

Comment: @charlietfl yes I know it is very complex :(

Comment: Goes back to my original suggestion of writing as many regex as you can and a parser for each

Comment: @charlietfl yup, exactly, that's why I have created this new question in order to find a specific solution for the two provided case studies. That solution would give me probably the basics to start creating all the rest that I'd need

Comment: start in a sandbox https://regex101.com/ ...once you determine a match  write a parser for each

Comment: @charlietfl not a regex boy here at all, i'd know how to write a (long, dirty, ugly) function for strings match tho

Comment: Will be a lot of work no matter how you do it so might as well start learning regex. There won't be many shortcuts

Comment: @charlietfl well, since it'd be a lot of work no matter what, I'd rather start writing in the ways I already know than spending time learning a new thing to then finally apply it to what I need.