# How to push to new array if string in array matches string in another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var words = ["27","-","28","August","663","CE"];
```

The string `August` is present in both and I need to push `August` into a new year multidimensional array:

```
dates.push({
    Day : [], 
    Month : [],
    Year : [],
    Prefix : []
});
dates[0].Time.push(d);
```

This is how I create the second array, so there is a loop we can use but I'm not sure how to check if a string is in the other array and if so, push it to new array.

```
var string = "27 - 28 August 663 CE";
var words = string.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
    words[i] += " ";
    // here we check matches and push
}
var array = words;
```

Comment: do you want to be on the *top questioners list* ? :0

Comment: @Jonasw limit is 6 questions in 24hour on stack.

Comment: Did you really mean to put all the months in a single element of the `months` array?

Comment: @Barmar didn't understand what you meant, what do you mean?

Comment: Haven't you just asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418539/how-to-push-and-split-a-date-into-a-mutidimentional-array

Comment: @webnoob I have indeed, do you have an answer for that?

Comment: @rob.m youre missing either a .split(", ") or some " ...

Comment: What I meant was, isn't it the same. I thought at first glance it was but perhaps I didn't look close enough.

Comment: @webnoob no it isnt. however ive simply answered booth ... ;)

Comment: @webnoob not it isn't but one answer after the other while I am testing out few solutions would eventually (hopefully) get to answering that question which is a tricky one

Comment: @Barmar ahh ok ok, updating the question, got it now, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `Set` for the months, to avoid that you have to loop over it, but can know in constant time whether you have a matching value:

```js
var months = new Set(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]);
var words = ["27","-","28","August","663","CE"];

const d = {
    days : [], 
    months : [],
    years : [],
    suffixes : []
}
for (const word of words) {
    if (months.has(word)) {
        d.months.push(word);
    } else if (+word < 32) {
        d.days.push(+word);
    } else if (+word < 2200) {
        d.years.push(+word);
    } else if (/\w+/.test(word)) {
        d.suffixes.push(word);
    }
}

console.log(d);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NB: use plurals for your properties so it is clear they are arrays, and don't start them with a capital as that is commonly reserved for classes/constructors. Also, a prefix is something that comes before. You want suffixes.

Comment: oh maaan! Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: actually /\w+/.test?

Comment: That means that for the suffix it will only allow letters, digits or underscore. Punctuation is ignored completely (like the hyphen). If you want only letters then do `/[a-z]+/i.test`

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter the words after a certain criteria (e.g. if theyre included in the months array):

```
dates.push({
  Day :  words.filter(word=>parseInt(word)&&word.length === 2),
  Month : words.filter(word=>months.includes(word)),
  Year : words.filter(word=>parseInt(word)&&word.length === 4),
  Prefix : ["i dont know what tnis is"]
});
```

Comment: thanks man, can you provide a bit more of an explanation please?

Comment: @rob.m shure, note that this will just work if you follow barmans advise...

Comment: actually i didn't understand what barman meant, what did he mean?

Comment: @rob.m ["a,b,c"] shall be ["a","b","c"]

Comment: ahhh ok ok, sorry was just my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object and check the lower case word.

```js
var months = { january: true, february: true, march: true, april: true, may: true, june: true, july: true, august: true, september: true, october: true, november: true, december: true },
    words = ["27", "-", "28", "August", "663", "CE"],
    result = [];
    
words.forEach(function (w) {
    months[w.toLowerCase()] && result.push(w);
});

console.log(result);
```