# How to remove all commas from a string and add white space?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given these two strings:

```
var a = "November 5, 1916";
var b = "October 5–10, 1592";
```

I am doing:

```
b.replace(' ', '').split(' ');
a.replace(' ', '').split(' ');
```

But I still get a comma and no white space. I need to be able to remove ALL commas from those strings and keep the white space in order to have:

```
var resultA = "November 5 1916";
var resultB = "October 5–10 1592";
```

**update**

I do need the `split()` afterwards as I need each string in an array.

Comment: I'm no js expert, but your calls to `replace` and `split` don't work with commas at all.

Comment: you probably should have done a search first on this question. 
 Its probably been answered a million times over.  Just search string replace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @MeghanArmes nope. I am splitting to have each single value into an array, but since there are commas or dashes and 5-10 and actually 2 distinct numbers, I'd also have to remove the dash and add white spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The split() method is not needed since you are not trying to turn the string into an array.

Just to remove all commas straighforwardly:

```
a.replace(',', '');
b.replace(',', '');
```

Comment: I am actually turning it into an array, will update the question.

Answer (score 8):

To replace all occurrences of a string with another string, using the following function:

```js
str.replaceAll(',', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is remove the commas, then you basically have a typo in your example. The first parameter to `replace()` should be the character(s) you want to remove. In your example, you are removing the spaces and keeping the commas. You need this:

```
b.replace('/,/g','');
a.replace('/,/g','');
```

Comment: this will only replace 1 comma

Comment: @thomasmeadows You're right thanks. How about taking away the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
var stringWithoutCommas = stringWithComas.replace(/,/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"
mystring.replace(/,/g , " ");
```

This will replace all the commas with space.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = "November 5, 1916";
var b = "October 5–10, 1592";
var r=/  |,/gi ;
$("#a").text(a.replace( r,""));
$("#b").text(b.replace( r,""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="a"></span>
<hr>
<span id="b"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var a = "November 5, 1916";
  var b = "October 5-10, 1592";


  $("#btn").click(function() {
    
    a = a.replace(",", "");
    b = b.replace(",", "");
    var c =  b.replace("-", " ");

    $("#a").text(a);
    $("#b").text(b);
    $("#c").text(c);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="a">a</p>
<p id="b">b</p>
<p id="c">c</p>

<button id="btn" type="button"> Click
```

Comment: with this same logic, i could remove the dash too 5-10, and add space . This is identical to the accepted answer btw :)

Comment: yea it looks a like a lot of activity has happened by the time i was done typing :)

Comment: basically I am trying to answer this and each time I get a new date format, I'll add it in the algorithm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417870/how-would-you-handle-different-formats-of-dates

Comment: yeah that is tricky you will need to define "templates", maybe regex will work best. Good luck.

Comment: exactly, thanks. btw way i tried `b.replace("-", "");` but the dash between 5 and 10 stays, why?

Comment: Because the '-' that you had is a little bit longer than normal, you can use that but will have to copy paste it.

Comment: different author for the 'split/join' solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150877/discussion-between-rob-m-and-otc).